# Hide ui-grid columns when windows becomes smaller

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

Is it possible to hide certain ui-grid columns if window as well as ui-grid becomes smaller? I want to set some priority which columns should remain visible when window becomes smaller and which are not as important. These should be hidden so other columns could have the required space to display data.

So for instance I want to keep column 1, 4 and 5 if window becomes smaller...

[image]

...but display all 5 if it's big enough.

[image]

I can't see anything such as `columns.minScreenWidth` in Kendo UI... I know there's `visible` property I can define, however I have no idea how to set it based on the size of the grid.

My current columnDefs:

```
vm.grid.columnDefs = [
        {
            name: 'one',
            displayName: 'Column of highest priority',
            enableHiding: false,
            minWidth: 400
        }, {
            name: 'two',
            displayName: 'Less Important',
            enableHiding: false,
            type: 'date'
        }, {
            name: 'three',
            displayName: 'Even Less Important',
            enableHiding: false
        }, {
            name: 'four',
            displayName: 'Should be visible',
            cellFilter: 'date:"dd/MM/yyyy"',
            enableHiding: true,
            type: 'date'
        }, {
            name: 'five',
            displayName: 'Should also be visible',
            visible: vm.showFithColumn,
            enableHiding: false
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to know the Windows width you can use `$window.innerWidth`.

So, an example could be:

```js
var windowsWidth=$window.innerWidth;

vm.grid.columnDefs = [
        {
            name: 'one',
            displayName: 'Column of highest priority',
            enableHiding: false,
            minWidth: 400
        }, {
            name: 'two',
            displayName: 'Less Important',
            visible: function(value){
                 return (windowsWidth>300)
             }
            type: 'date'
        }, {
            name: 'three',
            displayName: 'Even Less Important',
            visible: function(value){
                 return (windowsWidth>400)
             }
        }, {
            name: 'four',
            displayName: 'Should be visible',
            cellFilter: 'date:"dd/MM/yyyy"',
            visible: function(value){
                 return (windowsWidth>500)
             }
            type: 'date'
        }, {
            name: 'five',
            displayName: 'Should also be visible',
            visible: function(value){
                 return (windowsWidth>600)
             }
        }
    ];
```

Comment: Actually, visible: windowWidth>600 on it's own worked nicely. Thanks

Comment: Remember to adjust the value "300", "600" etc for the sizes you want.
if worked for you, please mark as correct answer :D

Comment: Yeah, now I just have to find a way to watch that width value to show/hide the columns dynamically.